# Angular2: +params['id'] not converting id:string into id:number

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Hi I'm trying to set up an Angular2 route based on `gallery/:id`. I'm using a tutorial/reading through the route documentation on angulars website and have ended with the code I have now. The problem I'm facing is my object id is defined as a string and in angulars solution, it is defined as a number.

The reason why I still want to keep the id as a string is one because I want the URL to display the title of the current gallery and secondly I want to use the id to reference a JSON file containing information particular to the route. Is this a bad practice?

The problem I'm having with the current code lies here:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
      this.projectService.getProject(id)
        .then(project => this.project = project);
    });
 }
```

I'm getting an error in typescript saying `Argument type 'number' is not assignable to parameter type of 'string'`

I believe this means one of two things, first that the id isn't being converted into a number and it's causing an error or the id is being converted into a number but since my class is defining it as a string it's flagging an error.

Is there a way around this so I can use route param as a string?

gallery.component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { Project } from '../project';
import { ProjectService } from '../project.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home.gallery',
  templateUrl: './home.gallery.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.gallery.scss'],
  providers: [ProjectService]
})

export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = params['id'];
      this.projectService.getProject(id)
      .subscribe( project => this.project = project);
    });
  }
}
```

project.service

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Project } from './project';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  private projectsUrl = 'data/project.json'; // URL to web API

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.projectsUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getProject(id: string): Observable<Project> {
    return this.getProjects()
      .map(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id));
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.project || {};
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to cast `+params['id']` at all? Your route param is string, your parameter in `getProject()` is string, your `id` is just a temporary middle man, and why do you want it to be number?

Comment: hmm I'm not really sure, I was trying to follow the tutorial and thought the route param might have to ba a number. Now that you point it out though that wouldn't really make sense. Are they converting their number into a string in the example? Or what function is +params['id'] playing?

Comment: so `param['id']` will always be a string. If you have some function that works on number value (e.g. `increaseId(currentId: number)`), you will need to cast a string to a number by using `+stringValue`. But because you are not, just remove that bloody `+` sign and you're all good.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem with the params, now I'm having trouble with the observables but I'll do some searching on that.

Comment: Params are serialized to the URL in the browsers URL bar, there is no way of telling if a part was previously a number or a string. This is why you need to take care of this yourself.